# Copy file from Application document directory and move to iPhone /Application folder- Objective C?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I have one ipa/deb file there at some server and through service call I download that file and save it to my application document directory (within app sandbox). This app is not the signed one and I have to install it directly/automatically on iPhone device without the help of any third party tool like Cyberduck/iExplorer even not the terminal. So how can I accomplish the complete task with coding part only if it is to grant root access to app or install the app. You can say this app will behave like Cydia for app installation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you writing code for jailbroken devices? because this will not be possible on non jailbroken iOS devices.

Comment: @rckoenes, Thanks for the prompt response. I know in this case the app will be rejected but I was trying this thing myself not for any app store app, I have found some of the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416091/sending-bundled-application-to-applications-folder, that says the same thing but when I tried with this it fails.

Comment: I do not think it is possible since the file systeem is locked is on non jailbroken devices.

Comment: ok and what about jailbroken phones? I believe that the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416091/sending-bundled-application-to-applications-folder says the same thing and the answer is also accepted one, although the thread is older one but still I think it should work, kindly share if you do have any idea?

Comment: The question you are revering to is for OSX not iOS. The filesystem on iOS is locked and you can't write outside of of your apps sandbox. What you want is only possible on jailbroke devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you mean `/Applications` instead of `/root/Applications` since there is no such folder (at least not on my iOS 5 device).

Since `/Applications` folder has is owned by `root` with `755` permissions. That means, non-root users can read/execute the files in that folder but not write to it. If you want to write to that folder, you need to run your app as `root`. The way to do this, somewhat ironically for you, is to have the app installed in `/Applications` folder. (I think) this is automatically done if you install the app through `Cydia`.

So to sum up: You can't move app to `/Applications` if you installed it through App Store (or ad hoc distribution). You need to install it through `Cydia` and it'll be installed directly in that folder.

Also, that answer you're referring to in comments, is about Mac OS, not iOS.

Comment: I have modified the question can you please now answer the question?

Comment: If your host app (the one downloading the unsigned app you wish to install - "payload app") is not running as root, it's not possible to do this as you want. You would have to get the user to install the host app through Cydia - not App Store. But if your users are willing to install apps through Cydia, they might as well directly install the "payload app".

Comment: thanks for the reply, this question is related to jailbroken devices so user can install the app directly to the device without even using Cydia, there are some other apps also exists in market that do the same. So any idea on that?

Comment: Which app are you talking about?

Comment: Weblin and Sibche is there which perform exactly the same task.

Comment: Both these apps are install through Cydia and thus have root access.

Comment: agreed but after installation these platforms do not use Cydia any more as all the apps that are installed from these apps do not have the root access. You can easily see after installation the app goes to /var/mobile/applications rather than /root/application.